# How to put Apple Watch into waterproof mode?

Tags: swift, apple-watch

I've got a swimming workout set up.

```
let configuration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
configuration.activityType = .swimming
configuration.locationType = .outdoor

do {
    workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: configuration) 
    workoutSession!.delegate = self
    healthStore.start(workoutSession!)
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Perform proper error handling here...
    fatalError("*** Unable to create the workout session: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
}
```

But my client is saying that the watch doesn't go into waterproof mode unless he manually makes it.

For context, "waterproof lock" is a mode that the Watch Series 2 is supposed to enter into when starting a swimming workout. From [an Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT205000):

> When you start a swimming workout, your Apple Watch automatically locks the screen with Water Lock to avoid accidental taps. When you're done, turn the Digital Crown to unlock the screen and clear any water from your Apple Watch. You hear sounds and may feel some water on your wrist.

This functionality does not appear to be working with my app.

I only have a Series 0 to test on, so I can't confirm what's happening with my code with regards to the waterproof lock.

Am I missing something to make the workout force the watch into waterproof mode?

Comment: What do you mean by 'waterproof mode'? Are you thinking of some specific functionality? Otherwise Apple's tech notes "about Apple Watch water resistance": https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT205000

Comment: Thank you for that link. I'm trying to get the "automatic" features working:

"When you start a swimming workout, your Apple Watch automatically locks the screen with Water Lock to avoid accidental taps. When you're done, turn the Digital Crown to unlock the screen and clear any water from your Apple Watch. You hear sounds and may feel some water on your wrist."

Comment: Apparently the Water Lock is not activating with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no "waterproof mode". My client was under the impression that there was.

The native Apple Exercise app has a button that locks the watch and ignores interaction until the digital crown is rotated. This is not currently reproducible in third party apps.

The solution I have found is to disable all buttons on the watch app. This way, buttons are not accidentally tapped while in the water. The user has to force touch the watch to re-enable the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Available since watchOS 4: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/2868458-enablewaterlock

`// Only an application which is in an active workout or location session and is foreground is allowed to enable water lock
    @available(watchOS 4.0, *)
    open func enableWaterLock()`

Call `WKExtension.shared().enableWaterLock()` when starting your swim / water workout.